# Getting Thumbnail from Movie in NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

My app allows the user to select a video from the ELCImagePickerController and I store that video in NSData. Below is the code I use to get the NSData.

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"ALAssetTypeVideo"]) {

        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary assetForURL:[[info objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

            unsigned long DataSize = (unsigned long)[rep size];

            Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(DataSize);
            NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:DataSize error:nil];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];//this is NSData may be what you want

            [self.imagesToUpload addObject:data];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];

        } failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
        }];  
}
```

I then call this function to retrieve the thumbnail from the movie's NSData, however movieURL is always returning nil..

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromMovie:(NSData *)movieData {

    // set up the movie player
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:movieData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:dataString];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:movieURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    NSLog(@"err==%@, imageRef==%@", err, imgRef);

    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];

}
```

Comment: are you trying to get a URL with the movie data?

Comment: but the movie data is not a URL to the asset you are trying to extract an image from but the asset itself

Answer (score 0):

NSURL will return nil for URLs that contain illegal chars, like spaces. Check if there is any. I guess you need to use -[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:].

```
 NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: movieData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: both urlString and url are returning null